# Remove lines between rows in WPF grid

Tags: wpf

I have the following XAML in a WPF application.   There are white horizontal lines between the rows.   Is there anything that can be done to remove them?

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Header" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Body" Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Footer" Height=".5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="#454d52"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="54" Text="" Padding="200,30,200,30"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF454D52"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Padding="50,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"/>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,50,0"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>



</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `SnapsToDevicePixels` on your top-most Grid:

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```